# MVC finding row in database not using primary key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Assuming I have the following class:

---

```
public class Item

{
     [Key]
     public int itemID {get; set;}
     public int typeID {get; set;}
}
```

---

I understand that finding a record in database usually is by the primary key, e.g.

```
Item item = db.Item.Find(id);
```

How do I find the record by another column? i.e. find all the records where `typeID = 1`?

Comment: Note that this has *almost* nothing to do with MVC itself - it's purely a function of your model and data access layer, which is generally agnostic toward the hosting application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Item item = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.typeID == 1);
```

Keep in mind, that if you are not using primary key, then there could be more than one item matching your query. You can use `FirstOrDefault` as in sample above to get first (if any) item which matches query.

To get all items with specified type id, use `Where`:

```
var items = db.Items.Where(i => i.typeID == 1);
```